# VS2010: How to change automatic generated XML documentation file name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, documentation-generation

I recently changed my project's dll name from `ObjectCreator1.1.dll` to `ObjectCreator.dll`. This project also creates an XML documentation (Properties->Compile->Generate XML Documentation file). Now the problem is that I have renamed my assembly name with all the proper steps, and when I compile my project I get the right .dll and .pdb files, but the file name of this XML file is always `ObjectCreator1._1.Template.xml`. Is there any way I can rename this file to `ObjectCreator.Template.xml`?

I tried compiling my project without "Generate XML Documentation file" checked, and I recompiled after that with the "Generate XML doc file" checked... but somehow it is still taking the old assembly name.

Any idea from where it is taking this old name from or how I can rename it? It is a VB.NET project.

Answer (score 0):

For a **WinForms** project it takes the name from the `Assembly Name` (specified in `My Project` under the `Application` tab).

I just changed the assembly name in my current project and recompiled, and a new XML file with the new name was generated.

For **library** projects, the name appears to be taken from the `Root Namespace` field instead.

If it's not working for you, try doing a full solution clean and rebuild.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Sutdio 2010 Premium

Comment: Have you tried modifying the Root Namespace instead?  I've just noticed your project is a library, whereas the one I was fiddling with was a WinForms app (oops).

Comment: Just tried that..still no change. This person who posted this below question had some diff. Problem but he has mentioned that he changed the path and the name of this Auto generated XML file.. but unfortunately I could not find the procedure.. I searched over all in all MSDN docs and everywhere : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978414/vs2010-autogenerated-xml-documentation-file-does-not-update?rq=1 .

Comment: For testing purpose I changed the assembly Name and root namespace to ObjecXXX and after compilation I got ObjecXXX.dll, ObjecXXX.pdb and again ObjectCreator1._1.Template.xml.

Comment: Got it.. the old Name was written in ObjectCreator.vbproj file.. after renamming there it is finally generating the right name!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem; made my lunch break slightly less dull.